# how to write a Google script for checking file names from drive based on sheet cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a drive folder with about 700 photos, each with a unique name.
I have a google sheet with file names in individual cells (J2:J)

I need to check that said file name actually exists in the folder, the script should return either yes or no.

I'm not a very experienced coder and would love some help with this.

Thank you.

Comment: About `a drive folder with about 700 photos`, in this case, are there subfolders?

Comment: No, no subfolders.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### Check for file names

```
function checkforfiles() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Your Sheet Name");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,10,sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().flat();
  const fldr  = DriveApp.getFolderById("Folder Id");
  let vo = vs.map(name => {
    let files = fldr.getFilesByName(name);
    return (files.hasNext()) ? ["yes"]:["no"]
  });
  sh.getRange(2,11,vo.length,1).setValues(vo);
}
```

Comment: When I'm trying to run this i'm getting the following error


`6:15:07 PM Notice Execution started
6:15:08 PM Error 
ReferenceError: file is not defined
(anonymous) @ Code.gs:8
checkforfiles @ Code.gs:6
`

Comment: Try it again. I had a type